# Hive Metastore shared by different clusters of same HDInsight version but different cluster type

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

As per this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-use-external-metadata-stores) from Microsoft all the clusters pointing to an external shared Hive Metastore have to be of the same HDInsight version. Does it mean that the clusters can be of varying type as long as they have the same HDInsight version? Because for the same HDInsight version cluster type could be either Hadoop, Spark, Interactive Query etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom metastore lets you attach multiple clusters and cluster types to that metastore. For example, a single metastore can be shared across Interactive Query, Hive, and Spark clusters in HDInsight.

**Example:** If you Hadoop cluster with HDI 3.6, it can be shared with Spark cluster with HDI 3.6 version.

**Important points to remember:**

- If you share a metastore across multiple clusters, ensure all the
  clusters are the same HDInsight version. Different Hive versions use
  different metastore database schemas.
- You can't share a metastore across Hive 2.1 and Hive 3.1 versioned
  clusters. Example: You can't share Hive metastore with HDInsight 4.0 and
  HDInsight 3.6.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: what if we have a Hive Metastore setup with HDInsight 4.0 , and accidentally someone creates a Hadoop cluster pointing to it with lower HDInsight version i.e. 3.6, what impact it will have on the Hive Metastore?